# TFS 2012 continuous integration deployment fails - Directory not empty

Tags: tfs

Sporadically get the error

> An error was encountered when processing operation 'Delete Directory'
>   on
>
> > 'D:\xxx'. The error code was
> >     0x80070091. The directory is not empty.

I'm using web deploy WMSVC and the user has full access to the root of the site (set up through IIS > Configure Web Deploy Publishing

EDIT

Or less frequently:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets (4377): Web deployment task failed. (Unable to perform the operation ("Delete File")  for the specified directory ("D:\xxx\bin\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll"). This can occur if the server administrator has not authorized this operation for the user credentials you are using.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_TO_SITE_FOLDER.)

I follow the instructions for the user (a domain user) but it makes no difference. The publish settings that get saved have *publishMethod="MSDeploy"* instead of WMSVC.

Note, it deploys correctly 95% of the time.

Comment: msdeploy uses the remote agent service I believe and wmsvc is the window management service. Two different things. If it is working with the MSDeploy one then I would start there. Its possible that sometimes the build agent hasn't let go of some stuff. I incidentally prefer the wmsvc. I don't know too much about the remote agent service.

Comment: @mizzle I would like to know if you resolved this issue, because i'm having it myself now.

Answer (score 2):

I know this sounds stupid, but do you have those folders open (or children thereof) on *any* computer?  Especially if you had a dead remote desktop session or someone accessing it over the network share it will get a denial to be able to delete the directory.

Burned me a number of times, you're issue may be different though.  I realize this is a late response, but found it while searching for my own issue and though I cuold help.

Comment: I've had a similar error (different path) where I've had the Build drop folder open via a network share. I'd be very surprised if someone else on the team had those folders open but it's possible.